# same code run on different versions of tensorflow but different gpu memory is allocated

Tags: tensorflow

In my two system(P40, CUDA9, CUDNN7), tf1.8 and tf1.12 are installed respectively, and the same piece of code runs in tf1.12 almost double the allocated gpu memory as in tf1.8.

I wrote the following code to simplify the comparison. At this time in tf1.8, 1241MiB gpu memory is allocated and in tf1.12, 737MiB gpu memory is allocated. How could I optimize the gpu memory allocation in tf? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
import tensorflow as tf                                                                                                              
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
config.allow_soft_placement = True
a=tf.get_variable('a',(100,100))
b=tf.get_variable('b',(10000,10000))
sess=tf.Session(config=config)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

Comment: Did you explicitly set all the float to be either 32-bit or 64-bit ? It could be that tf1.12 is using 64-bit float while tf1.8 is using 32-bit float.

Comment: I have checked, all the variables are float32.